# ImageView Android Image resourse resize

Tags: android, image, resize

How I resize only a image in a ImageView without resize the ImageView?

I need something like this:

[image]

Is the same image, but with ImageView different sizes

Comment: Use 'scaleType'  attribute

Comment: User different drawable icons like drawable-xxxhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi.

Comment: use this tools to generate different density images or icon for android https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: Use vector drawables, nine-patch or images with different densities.

Comment: I prefer [materialdesignicons.com/](https://materialdesignicons.com/) for material icons. If you already have an image than use [AndroidAssetStudio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) as suggested by @xFighter.

Comment: Just set wrap content for width and height

Comment: @sukumar wrap_content will now work in all case. What happen if image size is 500*500 or more?

Comment: @ChiragSavsani Please use vector assets to resize image for all screen

Comment: @sukumar I know that. I also suggest that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something like this:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bkgd_circle"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_person"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```